# Paypal express checkout android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout, recurring-billing

I am developing an Trucks app in mobile. I have trouble with paypal payment. For example if initial charge is less than  final charge I need to charge extra. 
So I have tried paypal Braintree sdk, Recurring billing is there but the problem is i can able to create plan and i can charge based on cycles(number of months).

I need to do like user needs to authorize only once, but if final charge is high i have to charge extra.

Is there any other way to perform additional charge in paypal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual way you do this is not to charge at first, but to place a hold on the amount.  Then you charge the full amount when you know it.

Comment: but I don't charge at first, we set money "Uncaptured" just for authorization, if I could not need to change the value I could just "Capture" money. But I need to change the amount